# How can I make my work devotional?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma

according to karma yoga I must do all work for krsna. my problem is that I have lots of physical pain because of which I cannot perform my daily work. physical pains in muscles prevent me from performing my duties. how can i perform karma yoga when i can't ever do my basic duties?

Comment: Since personal advice questions are off topic here, you should edit your question and make it generic/relevant to others. Maybe reword it as: How can people who are weak and not healthy perform karma yoga and dedicate it to Krishna as recommended in the Gita?

Answer (score 1):

What is karma? Ans- Yajna/Yagya. (BG 3/9)

Which is better form of Yajna/Yagya? Ans- Jap Yagya or Name Chanting (BG 10/25)

Tulsidas's Ramcharitmanas and Vinay Patrika, Kabir das, Guru Gobind and everyone says to chant particular name " Rāma ".

Yajna/Yagya is falsely translated as Sacrifice. It can be translated as Prayer, handclasp. It is वंदना in simple hindi.